# Can't boot because of Full Disc

Tags: dual-boot, mysql, disk-usage

I am running Ubuntu 20.10 LTS on a dual boot with Windows 10.

The other day I had the wonderful idea to run a data recovery utility... Long story short is I filled up my hard drive and now Ubuntu won't start.

- When booting into Ubuntu, I get some error akin to "Community MySQL won't start". Researching that alluded to issues about not enough disk space, and since I recently filled up my hard drive, I'm guessing MySql doesn't start due to a full disk.
- Booting into windows, I cannot give my Linux partition more space.
- I can boot into GRUB, although I can't find much use for it. Doing the "Clean" option doesn't seem to do anything. I have two kernels available - 5-8.53 and 5-8.55.
- My last idea before posting this question is to create a boot disk. I created a boot disk for 20.10, but that doesn't seem to work... Do I need to use a different distro than what I have currently?
- I believe I do not have a boot partition. This is my first linux box, and i didn't know what a boot partition was until 10 minutes ago.

I just need to delete one folder from my Linux partition. What is the easiest way to do that without booting into the OS? Please and thank you.

Comment: What happened with your USB 20.10? That should boot regardless of your full Linux partition.  Then mount your full partition, and delete what you need to. Don't confuse a /boot partition with an EFI partition, they are different things, and a Boot partition is only needed these days for special cases like maybe raid or lvm/encryption on your root.

Comment: I encountered an "id10T"error - I forgot I needed to press F10 to do the USB boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!!

First, I forgot I needed to press `F10` (or F-12 on some machines) to access the USB Boot thing.

Once I figured out how to correctly boot from USB, I was able to figure out how to delete files by [following the instructions here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198148/deleting-files-after-booting-from-a-usb-drive).

The only caveat to those instructions is to prefix the `fdisk` and `rm` commands with `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

If you get into trouble with your installed Linux ( Or windows ) OS, you can use the non persistent USB Ubuntu live installer to fix what you need to fix.

However, the OS partition can't be encrypted for a direct hard disk mount.

It is even possible to install Linux on to a USB in order to get a portable OS.